# Compute the stress curves for the half-circular arch beam

Tags: classical-mechanics, stress-strain, structural-beam

I'm very new to static mechanics and need some help to check my solution.

[image]

We have that,
$$R_A+R_B=0,$$
so given the equilibrium
$$P r/2 + R_B 2r=0,$$
we find that $R_B=-p/4$ and $R_A=p/4$. Now, for bending moment we have
$$m_x=R_B 2r + F(x-r/2).$$ 
How do we obtain $m_x$?

Comment: You need to define some of these variables.  Like I assume $R_A$ and $R_B$ are reaction forces at each support.  In that case, is this beam massless?

Comment: What is $P$ in your second equation. $F$? Then what is $p$ in your third equation? $F$ again? You need to be consistent

Comment: What is $x$ in your third equation? Is it the horizontal distance from A to B in terms of the radius $r$?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the supports are two pins as shown, and not a pin and a roller? Also, are you sure this is just a statics problem? The title of your post suggests mechanics of materials is involved.

I ask the first question because with two pins and a horizontal load, the problem would be statically indeterminate. In other words the equations for equilibrium alone would be insufficient to solve the problem. The reason is the horizontal reactions of the two pin supports to the applied horizontal force $F$ are redundant.

Your first equation is fine but only applies to the vertical reactions at the supports and assumes the beam is massless so that there is no vertical load (you didn't state that). But you need another equation for horizontal equilibrium, which would be

$$R_{Ah}+R_{Bh}+F=0$$

Where $R_{Ah}$ and $R_{Bh}$ are the horizontal reaction of the two pin supports. Equations for the sum of the moments about A or B, combined with your first equation of the vertical reactions, will allow you to solve for the vertical reactions, but not the horizontal reactions. For that you would only have 1 equation and 2 unknowns, $R_{Ah}$ and $R_{Bh}$. That is why the problem is statically indeterminate. The problem needs to include equations of deformation, which makes the problem a mechanics of materials problem and not just a statics problem.

Normally in statics if you have horizontal loading, you would have a pin and a roller support making it a simply supported beam. There would only be one horizontal reaction, the one at the pin, because a roller would provide no horizontal reaction.

Hope this helps.